# How do I create a login user that can only view data?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I'm working with MSSQL Server Management Studio 2014.

I am trying to create a login that can view a database's tables, functions and users. Also generate scripts for the database, but not run the scripts. The login shouldn't be able to delete, create, drop or insert anything in the database.

[image]

With this attempt the user was unable to view the functions in the database.

What should I do to create such a login?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by View the functions? What is your expectation?

Comment: I would like to be able to generate the function script on the management studio

Comment: `db_datareader`, `db_denydatawriter` for select, insert, but not update and delete, and a grant for VIEW ANY DEFINITION See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms191291.aspx and http://serverfault.com/questions/586446/is-there-ddl-viewer-role-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
USE [DataPump]
GO

declare @login VARCHAR(30) = 'UserRevoke'

declare commands cursor for
SELECT 'Grant View Definition ON ' + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + [name] + ' TO ' + '[' + REPLACE(REPLACE (@login, '[', ''), ']', '') + ']' 
FROM sys.all_objects s 
WHERE type IN ('P', 'V', 'FN', 'TR', 'IF', 'TF', 'U') 
    /*
    P - Stored Procedure 
    V - View 
    FN - SQL scalar-function
    TR - Trigger 
    IF - SQL inlined table-valued function
    TF - SQL table-valued function
    U - Table (user-defined)
    */
    AND is_ms_shipped = 0 
ORDER BY s.type, s.name 

declare @cmd varchar(max)

open commands
fetch next from commands into @cmd
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
  exec(@cmd)
  fetch next from commands into @cmd
end

close commands
deallocate commands
```